# Powershell's -replace() does not preserve line breaks, or I'm doing it wrong

Tags: powershell, text, replace

I have a text file with some lines of text and I want to insert into another text file.

```
aaa.txt:
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
ccccccccc
dddddddd
eeeeeeee

bbb.txt:
slkdfjlskdfj dlfjsldkfj slkdfjs
{{replace}}
sdlkfjslkfj sldkfjsld kfjsldk fjsldk f
sldkfjslkfjlskjflskdjf
sdkfjslkjflsklsdjkf
sldfkjslkfjlskfj
```

But when I replace {{replace}} with the contents of aaa.txt it puts all the text on one line- I want to preserve the line breaks from aaa.txt:

```
PS> $bbb = cat .\bbb.txt
PS> $bbb -replace('{{replace}}',(cat .\aaa.txt))
slkdfjlskdfj dlfjsldkfj slkdfjs
aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc dddddddd eeeeeeee
sdlkfjslkfj sldkfjsld kfjsldk fjsldk f
sldkfjslkfjlskjflskdjf
sdkfjslkjflsklsdjkf
sldfkjslkfjlskfj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-replace` replaces individual strings. `cat .\aaa.txt` returns an array of strings, which `-replace` then has to convert to a single string before `-replace` can do something with it -- hence your result. In PowerShell v3, the `-raw` parameter was added to `Get-Content` to circumvent this behavior, so if you have that, it's as simple as this:

```
$bbb -replace '{{replace}}', (cat -raw .\aaa.txt)
```

Comment: YES! I was hoping it would be that easy. I forgot that its actually an array of strings I'm passing it so that behavior makes perfect sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
($bbb -replace('{{replace}}',$aaa)) -replace " ","`n`r"
```

Comment: Actually , this will have an issue of replacing all of the spaces